# How to display products in spree which are available in stock first and then display not available products in last

Tags: spree

I want to display the product listing order in such a way that the product having stock should display first on the page and then not available in stock products will display after. So my question is as:

How to display/list the products in spree which are available in stock first and then display not available products in last.

Is there any built in function in spree commerce which is used for this?

Answer (score 0):

Although you've asked a very vague question i'll assume we mean the same thing. If you're aiming at displaying a list where the ones with stock comes up first, you would have to iterate through the list first, and then separate the ones with available stock and the ones with none, and then display them after in a sorted manner. Now I'm not sure what you're using but if you could sort the items based on decreasing order of stocks, then that should do the trick.

Comment: I am using ruby on rails with spree.

Answer (score 0):

SCM. If you would like to receive answers faster, you should visit official Spree commerce slack. There is over 5000 members that are active in terms of development. I'm more than sure they will be able to help you with any issues.

here is the link spree-commerce.slack.com

Best regards